# JPA OneToMany - List doesn't update after add/delete object, but is persisted in DB

Tags: list, jpa, one-to-many

I'm using JPA not Hibernate. I have a Problem with my Relationship as follows. I have a 1:N Relationship (Parent:Child).

On a JSP-Site, the Parent and the Children are displayed.
If I load the JSP-Site (for the first time) and save a Parent with a Child, all is ok. The Parent is saved and the Child is saved too to the DB with the foreign key.

After that, a second JSP-Site is displayed with the Parent and Children.

But if I go back to the first Site and save a second Child (adding Child) to existing Parent, the `childEntityList` is still the old one, I mean, the new Child is not inside this List, but inserted in the database.

Why the `childEntityList` is old and doesn't update?

The Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "Parent")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({...})
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "A_SEQ")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "p", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntityList = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>();
    // ...

    public List<ChildEntity> getChildEntityList() {
        return childEntityList;
    }

    public void setChildEntityList(List<ChildEntity> childEntityList) {
        this.childEntityList = childEntityList;
    }

    public void addChildEntityToParent(ChildEntity c) {
        this.childEntityList.add(c);
        if(c.getParent() != this) {
            c.setParent(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeChildEntityFromParent(ChildEntity c) {
        childEntityList.remove(c);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The Child:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "Child" )
@NamedQueries({...})
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "CHILD_ID" )
    private Long childId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Parent p;
    // ...

    public Parent getParent() {
        return p;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent p) {
        this.p= p;
        if(!p.getChildEntityList().contains(this)) {
            p.getChildEntityList().add(this);
        }
    }
```

Save-Code:

```
Parent p = new Parent(...);
ChildEntity c = new ChildEntity(...);
p.addChildEntityToParent(c);
childEntityFacade.create(c);
```

View-Code:

```
// ...
public doSomething(Parent p) {
    super(p);
}
// ...
List<ChildEntity> cList = p.getChildEntityList();
System.out.print("Size: " + c.size());
// ...
```

In the View-Code, the size of the `childEntityList` is every time the same even I add a Child.
Only when I restart the server, all Children of the Parent are displayed.

When is the `childEntityList` in the Parent Class filled?
Is it automatically, because of the `@OneToMany`?

Can someone explain it?

**Update:**
Should I merge the EntityManager every time when I add/remove a Child object from the Parent list or have I do some other things?

Comment: You need to set the parent record on the child ***before*** adding it to the collection of children. Also, I would highly recommend managing the bi-directional relationship from one side. As it is you have management split between the parent and child records.

Comment: As far as your display issue, I would recommend adding the child record to the parent, then saving the parent.  Saving a child as a separate transaction will not automatically update lists in already instantiated parents.

Comment: I don't understand you correctly, i think.
The Parent is existing, and i want to add one or more Children to the Parent.
I do that with my "addChildEntityToParent" in the Parent Class.
**(The merge issue was helping me)!**

Comment: And i set the parent object on the child too, in the "addChildEntityToParent", but **after** adding the child to the "childEntityList" in the parent class. I think that's correct, or not?

Comment: You are not creating a new parent record every time I assume, where is your code for creating a new child and adding it to an existing parent?

Comment: Of course, i don't creating a new parent every time. I can create a parent with and without a child. Then i can edit an existing parent e.g. to add or remove a child to/from a parent. I create a new child in my "Save-Code": Child c = new Child(name, ...); Then i add it to the childEntityList: p.addChildEntityToParent(c); and persist it in my Facade: childFacade.create(c); Since the issue with merge, my code is working, in db and the childEntityList.

Comment: Sorry, the code was not right: The name of the child class is ChildEntity and not Child!

Answer (score 5):

You need to maintain both sides of a bi-directional relationship. See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side).

Comment: I do exactly the same. In the parent class i have the addChildEntityToParent() Method, where i add the Child and in the child class i have the setParent() Method, where i set the parent of the Child.

Comment: What does childEntityFacade.create(c) do?  When do you persist the parent?  This is creating a new one, what code do you use to add a child to an existing parent.  If you only merge the child, then the parent will be out of synch, you need to merge both, or correctly edit your managed objects.

Answer (score 1):

> (I'm using JPA not Hibernate!)

I guess you meant that you are not using the Hibernate API.
JPA is only a persistence API specification and, by itself, does nothing.
So, if you're using JPA... you're using *something* to do the persistence.

JPA delegates the persistence work to a persistence engine such as Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA or something else.

You can configure your app to use JPA interfaces with a specific persistence provider, or if the app is running in a JEE container, then the JPA implementation should be provided for you: GlassFish (uses OpenJPA), WebLogic (uses EclipseLink), TomEE (uses OpenJPA).

> Should i merge the EntityManager every time when i add/remove a Child
>      Object from the Parent List...

You don't merge the EntityManager; you use it to merge the parent entity:

```
parent = em.merge(parent);
```

Relating to your question, when you use merge() in this way... (and because the mapping specifies CascadeType.ALL) then upon reloading page ("Site 1") you should get the refreshed parent object with an updated object network containing changes you made prior to merge(parent), including any newly added children.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to merge parent entity. I was having same issue and it got resolved once I merged parent entity. 
Also you need to maintain both sides of the relationship.